# Converting image with transparency to CMYK tiff results in solid black alpha channel

Tags: imagemagick, tiff, imagemagick-convert, cmyk

I have an image with a transparent background which I want to convert into a TIFF image in cmyk colorspace.

```
convert source.png -compress LZW -colorspace cmyk -profile CoatedFOGRA39.icc cmyk.tif
```

While the created file has indeed 5 channels (cmyk + transparency), the transparent background will be shown black.
Adobe Photoshop can read this file properly, but the file cannot used in Adobe InDesign, since the transparency isn't working.

If I manually save the file again with Photoshop, it's repaired and InDesign will use the transparency.

[image]

So I assume the generated file is broken. But why? How I can solve this?

I also tried a different approach I found online, e.g. extracting the alpha mask and reapplying it again, but this did not help.

```
convert -depth 8 -colorspace sRGB source.png -alpha Extract mask.png
convert \( -depth 8 -colorspace CMYK source.png -alpha Activate \) mask.png -compose copyopacity -composite cmyk.tif
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have shared an annotated screen-grab of your files rather than the actual files so it is hard to tell what is going on. Please share the original PNG, the TIFF created by ImageMagick and the TIFF *"cured"* by Photoshop - you can use **Google Drive** or **Dropbox** or somesuch if you can't post them on SO. Thank you.

Comment: It is likely the type of transparency saved. See the -define tiff:alpha=associated|unassociated|unspecified at https://imagemagick.org/script/defines.php. I am not sure which you need. So try each option.

Answer (score -1):

Place the file in Illustrator as a linked photo;
File>Document>Color Mode>CMYK  (if it isn't already)
Then embed the file, it will become a transparent CMYK with minimal photo changes.